# Area of a square javascript program

Tags: javascript, html, area

Here is the following code:

```
<h2>Area of a Square (A = s<sup>2</sup>)</h2>
    <form>
    <label class = "left">Side Length: </label>  <input id = "areaSquare" type = "text" class = "right" /> <br />
    <label class = "left">Answer: </label>  <input id = "answerAreaSquare" type = "text" class = "right" /> <br />
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "areaSquare(); return false" />
    </form>

function areaSquare(side)
{
side = document.getElementById("areaSquare").value;
var answer = side*side;
document.getElementById("answerAreaSquare").value = answer;
}
```

I thought this was a pretty simple program but i have no idea why this is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a global function from an onclick attribute. Browsers do really odd things to the scope of intrinsic event attributes (like onclick) and when used in a form control, there will be local variables referencing all the form controls by their ids.

Since you have an element with an id that matches the global function, it gets a variable in a local scope and masks the function.

You can test this with:

```
 onclick="alert(areaSquare); areaSquare(); return false"
```

The quick and dirty hack is to rename one of them.

---

The better solution is to *avoid using globals* in the first place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Area of a Square (A = s<sup>2</sup>)</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="areaSquare">Side Length: </label>
      <input id="areaSquare"> <br>

      <label for="answerAreaSquare">Answer: </label>
      <output id="answerAreaSquare"></output> <br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<script>
// IIFE for scope
(function () {

  // Locally scoped function
  function areaSquare(event) {
    var side = document.getElementById("areaSquare").value;
    var answer = side*side;
    document.getElementById("answerAreaSquare").value = answer;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  // Event handler bound with JS instead of HTML
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', areaSquare);
})();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know it creates a global that overrides it (it's obvious when it says object is not a function, how ever it seems I can't access it directly from window.areaSquare, so where is it held?) p.s. no idea why all the downvotes in this question :O

Comment: I'd forgotten the scoping rules for intrinsic event attributes (mostly because they are stupid and confusing). Corrected explanation in the answer.

Comment: Now it makes sense, p.s. calling window.areaSquare() would have been the simplest solution.